# Creating Temporary Table for another query

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query in mysql which needs to use a table with numbers from 1 to 10 in a single column. For that purpose, I'm trying to create a temporary table with UNION command and reference it my query. The code is as follows;

```
create temporary table numbers (

N int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

)

UNION

insert into numbers  (N)

values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
```

While these simple comannds work fine one by one, I cannot manage to execute them with UNION. What would be the problem and if it is not a proper use; what could be the alternatives?

Edit: This error message appears in MySql Workbench

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into numbers (N)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? what doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you please re-check the post? I add the error message. @sagi

Comment: You should read the [mysql doc about `union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: UNION has the purpose of merging to SELECT results – you can not use it to concatenate just any two arbitrary statements.

Comment: You are right; but, how to combine these 2, then? @CBroe

Comment: What is the problem with executing them separately, one after the other?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?...

Comment: Because it is going to executed by Ruby on Rails on an html based page. @CBroe

Comment: Trying to use numbers table in another query. @sagi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a <kbd>;</kbd>, like this:

```
create temporary table numbers (
    N int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
);

insert into numbers (N)
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
```

Comment: Well, it worked; but, adding another query with the same way gives syntax error again.  @RC.